# How to extract timestamp and remove tailing portion from weblog using regex in pyspark?

Tags: regex, pyspark, weblog

I am doing some practice on weblog parsing and here is a question on regex:

The log file is in the format of:

> in24.inetnebr.com - - [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 1839

I need to get the timestamp, here is what I have now:

```
regexp_extract('value', r'((\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{4}))', 1).alias('timestamp'),
```

This returns me:

> 01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 -0400

My question is what does -0400 means? time zone? How do I remove it?

Comment: Do you have any understanding of how regular expressions work? Because it should be very obvious to you which part of the regular expression matches `-0400` in that string. And yes, it's a time zone.

Comment: Regex is honorsly so confusing me, but I am willing to learn because it is really powerful. All I want to know is how to get rid of the -0400 and all I  need to do is to remove `-\d{4}`

Comment: That is exactly right. `\d` is a number and `{4}` means there are four of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** - that's a *timezone*.

You can simply remove it by eliminating `-\d{4}` part of the pattern. So this is what you're looking for:

```
regexp_extract('value', r'((\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))', 1).alias('timestamp'),
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oH4xS8/1)

Also as a explanation:

- `-` matches a dash plus a space after it literally
- `\d` matches a digit
- `{4}` limits it to only 4 digits